# Where/whom can I look/contact to find historical minutes of murder trials in former Yugoslavia (circa 1925)?

Tags: trial, research, history

I am writing an article about an alleged female serial killer that committed over 30 murders in former Yugoslavia (now Serbia, possibly in the town of Zrenjanin) around 1925. I have found several US newspapers reporting the crimes from May 1925 where they wrote that she will soon have a preliminary hearing.

Following that trail, where or whom can I contact to find the minutes of this alleged hearings or trial?

Comment: Some historians from the zone where the crimes happened could be a good place to start; even if they do not know about the crimes they can point you to institutions that could have documentation. Hemerotheques could be interesting. Also some geograph could be of help (`in former Yugoslavia (near or around Bucharest)`, did you mean Romania?). Do not get high hopes of retrieving the original records, though, even without taking into account the rough times the area has passed, historical records are routinely destroyed because it is expensive to keep them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, she was originally from Romania but seemed to have committed most of her crimes in former Yugoslavia (now Zrenjanin in Serbia). Thank you for your suggestion above, I will try that.

Comment: I assume the OP is referring to [Vera Renczi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vera_Renczi) whose "*story has surfaced repeatedly, but without traceable details such as specific dates of her birth, marriages, arrest, conviction, incarceration or death.*"